# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.map.setNativeProps') ( react-native run-android)

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, react-native-maps

I am having this error while running the app on android.

[screenshot of phone error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeteB.jpg)

I saw the thread on GitHub([Github issue](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj4h_SK0Y32AhWfyIsBHfu1BmgQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Freact-native-maps%2Freact-native-maps%2Fissues%2F3663&usg=AOvVaw2XSyrhapzX_LMXgSlye5k7)) But it is for iOS and I am specifically using this for the android applications.

```
ERROR  Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

and

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.map.setNativeProps')
```

I am using `react-native-maps` module. and I tried reinstalling already, cleared cache. Even cleaned the build cache, and For more, I had issues with Emulators too, so I reinstalled Android studio.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO , for getting a better feedback for your questions it is better to add details, part of code you used , used libraries and the one which causes the problem.
here you can find more details on how to ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask